# Multiple tasks that do the same

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a project that create a x number of tasks that do the same thing, open the same Excel file, but in different intervals. The problem comes when two of the tasks run at the same time, a read only file errors with macros. I tried to put a limit in the bat file that the tasks run, first stopping open other excel files and before do the same with other tasks, but It doesn't work. There is the last code that I wrote.

```
@ECHO OFF

TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq TASKENG.EXE" 2>NUL | FIND /I "TASKENG">NUL && (
    START %~dp0myExcelFile.xlsm
    EXIT
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the executable you want to detect is `taskeng.EXE` ? Perhaps it might be `taskeng.BAT`??

Comment: The cmd window name put "taskeng.exe", Is not the same?